# Как через API (в программном коде) прикрутить картинку к товару в minishop2

Tags: файлы, modx, изображения, minishop2

Как прикрутить картинку к товару в minishop2 (галерея)?
Я получаю товар вот так:

```
$last_product = $modx->getObject('msProduct', array('pagetitle' => $pagetitle, 'parent'=>$parent ));
```

Как к last_product прикрутить картинку, которая находится на сервере, через API minishop2?
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Это делается очень просто оказывается:

```
$data = [
'id' => 'id продукта',
'file' => 'путь к файлу',
];

$response = $modx->runProcessor('gallery/upload', $data, [
'processors_path' => MODX_CORE_PATH . 'components/minishop2/processors/mgr/',
]);
```